# Import functions of a dynamically loaded module

Tags: elixir

I have the following two files:

```
# script.exs
Code.eval_file("module.ex");

import MyModule # Doesn't work
my_function() # What I want
```

```
# module.ex

defmodule MyModule do
  def my_function() do
    IO.puts "My Function"
  end
end
```

When running `elixir script.exs`, it errors with the following message:

`** (CompileError) script.exs:3: module MyModule is not loaded and could not be found`

However, if you would write `MyModule.my_function()`, the code runs without errors.

So, is it somehow possible to import functions from a dynamically loaded module?

Comment: when you call `Code.eval_file("module.ex");` this imports a Module but unless you know it's name you can't call the functions defined in that Module.  When you write `MyModule.my_function()` you using the necessary knowledge (the Module's name).  You could adopt a naming convention for your `.ex` files so that are named by the Module it contains - assuming there is only one such . e.g.  `Code.eval_file("MyModule.ex");`

Comment: It's not about the Module name or anything, I just want the functions of the module to be available without the module name in front of it.

Comment: As far as I understand: the only way in Elixir to call a function without prefixing it with a module-name is if that function is called by code contained within the same module - which does not seem to be your case.

Comment: Normally you can use `import` for that case, see [this guide](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#import). I'm trying to get this to work for dynamic modules tho, which does not seem to work

Comment: DId you first compile the external module before trying to import it: `import MyModule` ?

Comment: In the iex shell you can compile the module using the following "command": `c "module.ex"`

Comment: In the IEx shell, it works. But I need it in a script called with `elixir script.exs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elixir is a compiled language and even what has a `.exs` extension and what is called *script*, is to be compiled into BEAM before execution.

The issue is `import MyModule` cannot be compiled because at the moment the compiler knows nothing about this module. The good news is we might fool the compiler.

Put all the code you need into a separate file:

```rb
# script.ex

import MyModule
my_function()
```

and use `runner.exs` script which will be compiling both:

```rb
# runner.exs

Code.eval_file("module.ex")
# IO.inspect Code.ensure_loaded(MyModule)
Code.eval_file("script.ex")
```

Now `runner.exs` would happily call `my_function()`.